# How to get help for "snippet::shinyapp" object?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

There is an object in R (or RStudio) which can write a chunk of code. For example 'shinyapp' write the initial code for a shiny app.

[image]
[image]

But this does not behave like any other R object.

```
?shinyapp
# No documentation for ‘shinyapp’ in specified packages and libraries:
# you could try ‘??shinyapp’
```

My questions are:

1. What are these object called?
2. How to get help for this kind of object?
3. How can I make an object like this?

Thanks...

Comment: There is a difference between R's help ("man pages", from an unix-y term for manual page) and code snippets (which is what your mouse is looking at above). A snippet is really just a macro that expands to the code you see in the yellow to the right, which happens (in this case) to reference three functions: the use of `fluidPage`, the *definition* of a function named `server` (that you have to populate), and the use of `shinyApp` (capital "A"). If you need help with a snippet, just read the snippet to see what is included, then read help for the code within.

Comment: @r2evans Is that object called 'code snippets'??

Comment: (Yes, sorry, I corrected myself in my second comment. I've deleted the first mis-guided comment.) A code-snippet is provided by the RStudio IDE, providing an easy way to start "something" in your project. I don't use them, but a quick search for "rstudio snippet" revealed https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets (which looks like it was updated *today* by JJ, very convenient!).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @r2evans for your help. From the link (shared by @r2evans on the comment box) I got all of my answers.

**1. What are these object called?**

These are called 'Code snippets'.

**2. How to get help for this kind of object?**

[Help Page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets)

**3. How can I make an object like this?**

RStudio -> Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Editing -> Edit Snippets -> R

**Step-1:** Add your code (selected) and save

[image]

**Step-2:** Type your snippet on console/script

[image]

**Step-3:** Hit Tab

[image]